# infer template string with dynamic number

Tags: typescript

```
type Test = T extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}` ? Rest : never;
```

This works when you infer with a static string

```
Test<'test.test'>  // 'test'
```

is it possible to infer correctly with a dynamic number? and potentially treat that dynamic number as string '0'

```
Test<`test.${number}`> // will result never
```

Comment: I don't see a way to do that.  Template literal types like this were introduced in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598) but I don't know that it was considered a use case.  Maybe you should file a feature request?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a dynamic number to a Test type. Cusom types can be created only based on created types. So, it is possible to infer correctly, not with a dynamic number but a type.

```
type Test<T> = T extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}` ? Rest : never

type Value = 'value'

type Test1 = Test<`key.${Value}`>       // 'value'

// or

const val: Value = 'value'
type Test2 = Test<`key.${typeof val}`>  // 'value'
```